# Rails ActiveRecord Rollback with redirect not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, activerecord

I have an action that performs a series of validations inside an each loop, committing to the database the value of each `EventSubscription` created in `EventSubscription.create!`.

If some of the validations fail, I want to rollback the previously committed transactions. In order to do so, I put the code inside an `ActiveRecord:Base.transaction` block, but when a validation fails and an exception is raised, the rescue block is not even executed and therefore does not redirect to the indicated page, and I want to redirect to that page. What can be wrong here? Can you please help?
Thanks in advance!

Here is my action code:

```
def download_subscriptions_file

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do

  begin


    # ambiente para o qual vao ser criadas as subscricoes
    @environment = Environment.find(params[:env_id])

    uploaded_file = params[:file]

    if uploaded_file

      # Le e faz parse do ficheiro carregado
      file = File.read(uploaded_file.path)

      parsed_file = JSON.parse(file)

      # logger.debug {parsed_file["eventSubscriptions"]}

      # obtem as ARS e grava na tabela entities da BD do backoffice
      parsed_file["eventSubscriptions"].each do |code, event|

        # logger.debug {event}


        # procura o evento correspondente, pois tem de existir na BD do BO
        db_event = Event.find_by(display_name: code)

        if !db_event

          raise Exception.new("Não foi possivel importar o ficheiro pois não foi encontrado qualquer evento na BD com o nome #{code}")

        end

        event.each do |entity_code, subs|

          # logger.debug {subs["_description"]}

          # procura o tipo de endpoint correspondente, pois tem de existir na BD do BO
          endpoint_type = EndpointType.find_by(description: subs["endpointId"])

          if !endpoint_type

            raise Exception.new('something bad happened!')

          end

          # procura a aplicacao no endpoint correspondente, pois tem de existir na BD do BO
          endpoint_app = EndpointApp.find_by(description: subs["endpointAppId"])

          if !endpoint_app

            raise Exception.new('something bad happened!')

          end

          if entity_code != "default"

            # procura a entidade correspondente, pois tem de existir na BD do BO
            entity = Entity.find_by("code LIKE ?", "#{entity_code}%")

            if !entity

              raise Exception.new('something bad happened!')

            end

            active = "f"

            # Verifica se a subscricao esta ou nao ativa para comparar com a que esta na BD e decidir se eh para mudar
            if subs["status"] == "active"
              active = "t"
            end

            # logger.debug { "entity->#{entity.code} #{entity.name}" }

            # So cria/atualiza se nao existir a subscricao na BD para o ambiente em causa
            entity_subs = EventSubscription.find_by(entity_id: entity.id, active: active, environment_id: @environment.id)

            if !entity_subs

              EventSubscription.create!(event_id: db_event.id, entity_id: entity.id, description: subs["_description"],
                                        active: active, endpoint_type_id: endpoint_type.id, endpoint_app_id: endpoint_app.id,
                                        environment_id: @environment.id)

            end

          end

        end

      end # parsed_file["eventSubscriptions"].each

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to env_event_subscriptions_path(env: @environment.id), notice: "Ficheiro de subscrições importado com sucesso para a BD do BackOffice no ambiente de #{@environment.name}." and return}
      end

    else

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to env_event_subscriptions_path(env: @environment.id), alert: 'Não foi selecionado qualquer ficheiro para importar.' and return}
      end

    end


  rescue => exception

    logger.error {"event_subscriptions_controller.download_subscriptions_file -> Ocorreu um erro ao importar o ficheiro de susbcricoes: #{exception.message}"}

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html {redirect_to env_event_subscriptions_path(env: @environment.id),
                               alert: "Ocorreu um erro ao importar o ficheiro de susbcrições: #{exception.message}" and return}

    end

  end

end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Instead of raising `Exception.new("message"`) raised only the message (`raise "message"`) and changed `rescue => exception` to `rescue Exception => e`, and printed the corresponding message.

Found the solution here: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Thanks anyway!